# Python - Garbage collection very slow, can't disable gc

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, garbage-collection, profiling

I am developing a program that uses `pandas` dataframes and large dictionaries. The dataframe is read from a CSV that is approx. 700MB.

I am using Python 3.7.3 on Windows

I noticed that the program I am running is extremely slow, and slows down after each loop of the algorithm.

The program reads every line of the dataframe, checks some conditions on every item of every line of the `df`, and if those conditions are met, it stores the item and his state in a dictionary. This dictionary can get pretty big.

I have tried profiling my code with `CProfile` and I have found that the `garbage-collector` is the function that uses up about 90% of the execution time.

I have seen similar problems resolved by calling `gc.disable()` but this did nothing for me.

Weirdly (I have no idea if this is normal) but if I `print(len(gc.get_objects()))` as the first line of the code I get `51053` which seems a lot considering no function has been called yet.

My `CProfile` attempt : (on a small chunk of the CSV, as it would take hours to complete the attempt on the full CSV)

```
cProfile.run('get_pfs_errors("Logs/L5/L5_2000.csv")', 'restats.txt')


import pstats
from pstats import SortKey
p = pstats.Stats('restats.txt')
p.sort_stats(SortKey.CUMULATIVE).print_stats(10)
p.sort_stats(SortKey.TIME).print_stats(10)
```

Here are the stats from `CProfile` :

```
Tue Jun 18 15:40:19 2019    restats.txt

         1719320 function calls (1459451 primitive calls) in 7.569 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 819 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.569    7.569 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.001    0.001    7.569    7.569 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.568    7.568 C:/Users/BC744818/Documents/OPTISS_L1_5/test_profile.py:6(get_pfs_errors)
        1    0.006    0.006    7.503    7.503 C:\Users\BC744818\Documents\OPTISS_L1_5\utils\compute_pfs_rules.py:416(compute_pfs_rules)
        1    0.197    0.197    7.498    7.498 C:\Users\BC744818\Documents\OPTISS_L1_5\utils\compute_pfs_rules.py:323(test_logs)
      264    0.001    0.000    6.532    0.025 C:\Users\BC744818\Documents\OPTISS_L1_5\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:982(__setitem__)
      529    0.010    0.000    6.158    0.012 C:\Users\BC744818\Documents\OPTISS_L1_5\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3205(_check_setitem_copy)
      528    6.125    0.012    6.125    0.012 {built-in method gc.collect}
      264    0.004    0.000    3.430    0.013 C:\Users\BC744818\Documents\OPTISS_L1_5\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:985(setitem)
      264    0.004    0.000    3.413    0.013 C:\Users\BC744818\Documents\OPTISS_L1_5\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:183(__setitem__)


Tue Jun 18 15:40:19 2019    restats.txt

         1719320 function calls (1459451 primitive calls) in 7.569 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 819 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      528    6.125    0.012    6.125    0.012 {built-in method gc.collect}
      264    0.405    0.002    0.405    0.002 {built-in method gc.get_objects}
        1    0.197    0.197    7.498    7.498 C:\Users\BC744818\Documents\OPTISS_L1_5\utils\compute_pfs_rules.py:323(test_logs)
 71280/33    0.048    0.000    0.091    0.003 C:\Users\BC744818\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py:132(deepcopy)
   159671    0.033    0.000    0.056    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
      289    0.026    0.000    0.026    0.000 {built-in method nt.stat}
167191/83791    0.024    0.000    0.040    0.000 C:\Users\BC744818\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py:333(_iterencode_dict)
  8118/33    0.019    0.000    0.090    0.003 C:\Users\BC744818\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py:236(_deepcopy_dict)
167263/83794    0.017    0.000    0.048    0.000 C:\Users\BC744818\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py:277(_iterencode_list)
 1067/800    0.017    0.000    0.111    0.000 C:\Users\BC744818\Documents\OPTISS_L1_5\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:253(__new__)
```

Comment: I encountered similar problems when processing large DataFrame and disabling the `garbage-collector` was useless. If I remember correctly, the problem was looping references. I managed to solve the issue by changing the way I was processing the DataFrame. Can you provide some details about this loop you do on your DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @user9993950, I solved it thanks to you.

When I tested this program, I had a `SettingWithCopyWarning` but I wanted to fix the speed of the program before fixing this warning.

Yet it so happens that by fixing the warning I also greatly increased the speed of the program and `gc` is no longer taking up all of the running time

I don't know what caused this though, if someone knows and wants to share the knowledge please do.